# Is there a reason to define type aliases in any program

Tags: c++, portability

I have started to learn c++ for some time ago. It is a big subject and I am not very use to it yet. Thus is this question asked more of curiosity, than something else.
In the book that I read to now learn there is a discussion about portability. I agree that the discussion comes quite earky for someone in the beginning of their learning period, but when reading I came to Think about something.

What I wonder is: is there ever is a reason to define custom type to use instead of the fundamental builtin types? For example, would it be useful to define a type `int_c` as in "int custom"? The reason I think about this is since some code may be compiled for example both a 32-bit compiler and a 64-bit compiler. It seems as if it would be easier since if you change platform and all the integers are defined as `int_c` instead of `int`, since the latter would require changing type in every place an int is used?

However, I also know that `<cstdint>` contains definitions of different integer as `int64_t`. However I have not heard of a header with floating Point types.

So to conclude: Is there a reason to define custom integers or floats like `int_c` or `double_c` Or int other case what is the best apporach?

Comment: "Custom types" usually include aggregate types (structs, classes, unions, and so on). Are you intentionally ignoring those and focusing on `typedef`? If so, perhaps you should update the question and title to refer to type aliases/typedefs.

Comment: Beside the portability, i use them internally sometimes for documentation only on function/constructor-arguments to documentate if a index starting by zero(i_index) or 1(i_no). whereat i by myself say: everything is allowed internally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is sometimes a reason to do so, however `<stdint.h>`  (in C99) or `<cstdint>`  (in C++03 or beter) make them less obvious.

First, there is a readability issue. If you define

```
typedef unsigned myhash_t;
```

and later always use `myhash_t`  for numbers which are in fact hashes, you ease the understanding of your code. This does not help much against your own mistakes (e.g. forgetting to declare a parameter as `myhash_t`  even if it is an hash) but it does enhance readability.

Then with `<stdint.h>`  (etc...) you have many new integral types (most of them being system-specific synonyms of e.g. `int`  and `long`), like `int64_t`  (a signed int of exactly 64 bits), `uintptr_t`  (an unsigned integer with the same size as pointers), `int_fast8t` (an integral type, which is computed quickly, of at least 8 bits, but it could be 16 bits if they run faster, etc...)

At last, you may place preprocessor tricks with e.g. `#if` combined to such `typedef`-s. For instance, you could define a color encoding as having 3 RGB (or 4, RGBA) components of

```
 typedef uint8_t color_t;
```

but some preprocessor trick might make that an `uint16_t` ....

FWIW, Ocaml and Ada are doing better than C++ in that respect. They are able to define *private* integral types (see e.g. [§7.9.2 in Ocaml ref](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc76).), on which arithmetic is forbidden (unless explicitly allowed). In C++ you could have `class MyHiddenInt { int x; /*etc*/ };`  but it may be differently represented and handled (i.e. produce less efficient machine code) than some `int`.  Details are of course [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific. On Linux/x86-64 with `-O2` optimization the [GCC 4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) generated code (e.g. for an addition) would be the same.

These private integers sometimes make sense. For example on Unix and Posix file descriptors are `int`-s but doing any arithmetic on them is non-sense. (likewise for `myhash_t` probably, but you cannot express that constraint in C++).

For floating numbers it is even more important. On some processors (e.G. some GPGPUs), `double`  precision arithmetic is so slow that you want to avoid it. On our laptop & dekstop PCs, it is the opposite: you almost always want to use `double`   (which today means IEEE754 64 bits floating point), and use `float`  (or `short`) only to squeeze memory consumption.  These choices are really processor specific (not the same on a tablet or a supercomputer).

You could go even further, and have a type analysis which take into account physical dimensions. So you forbid (at compile time) adding kilograms with amperes or watts, and that the product of a speed (in meter per second) with a time (in second) is a length (in meter) which should not be acceptable as a file descriptor or an hash.

Read about [abstract data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it have helped a lot. But then there is the floating point types. I have a little hard to get a grasp of them. For example, as I understand it, a `double` for a 32-bit compiler, has the same size as a `float` for a 64-bit compiler. Yet I have not read anything about custom types for floating point types.

Comment: No, `double`  are 64 bits both on Linux/i386 -ie. 32 bits- and on Linux/AMD64 -ie 64 bits-

Comment: C++ can privatize integer types too: `class MyHiddenInt { int x; };`

Comment: But that makes an object, which e;g. is often handled differently (e.g. when passing it as an argument). The generated machine code is usually not the same (but that depends on the ABI)

Comment: I disagree with that statement... unless you have a really (really really!) crappy compiler. Even naive compilers should have no overhead/difference in machine code here.